# Result Set return null value

Tags: java, mysql, database

I'm having a trouble when retrieving in a very simple SELECT query.
I'm trying to retrieve all information from table 'db_con_type' and put them in array String of dbChoices.

Database:

The Select query works fine in report designer. Sorry i can't upload the images since i'm new here.

Code:

```
public void setDbTypeChoices()
    {
       try
        {
            con2db connect2db = new con2db();
            con = connect2db.aksesDatabase();
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM db_con_type";

            rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

            int i = 0;
            while(rs.next())
            {
                this.dbChoices[i] = rs.getString("DB_Type");
                i++;
            }

            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            ps.close();
            con.close();

            //Close Connection
            connect2db.tutupKoneksi();
        }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
           System.out.println("SQL ERROR 1 = " + e.getMessage());
           System.out.println("SQL ERROR 2 = " + e.toString());
       }
    }
```

Error:

SQL ERROR 1 = null

SQL ERROR 2 = java.lang.NullPointerException

Question:

Any idea what is happening? Any Solution?

Thanks

Comment: Seems the connection is null. Can you check if it so?

Comment: Try debugging the code in some IDE

Comment: When you face a NullPointerException, it is better to print the whole stacktrace in order to see the line where the problem arose.

Comment: Resultset never returns NULL unless Connection is NULL

Comment: The connection is good since i get 2 results from the query. but, the error still occur and that confuses me.

Comment: Found the problem. it's because of the ps.close() code.. since i don't use it here but i close it and it rises a problem.. thanks to the printStackTrace idea by Luiggi.

thanks for all answers. i really appreciate it.. :D

Comment: @DeddyFeryanto, please consider [answering your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/12513) along the lines of your last comment.

Comment: i'll do that in 7 more hours due to not allowed self answer for newcomer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the way, it is a good practice that if you are handing `ResultSet` that you first check if the result set returned is not null before operating on it e.g. `rs.next()` which will give you a NPE if `rs` is `null`.

```
if(rs != null) {
    while(rs.next()) {
        this.dbChoices[i] = rs.getString("DB_Type");
        i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. it's because of the ps.close() code..

since i don't use it here but i close it and it rises a problem..

thanks to the printStackTrace idea by Luiggi.
thanks for all answers. i really appreciate it.. :D